# Revive Adserver 3.1.0 force refresh statistics

Tags: php, ssh, openx, advertisement-server

I'm testing the **Revive Adserver** (formerly **OpenX**) and need to see actual statistics, but it always caches for a long time.

Is there any ways to rebuild Revive statistics?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the statistics are refresh each hour. And the maintenance engine needs to set 60 mim (in admin settings).